Какой использовать метод вывода фото и текста в callback?
Ну подскажите пожалуйста, есть следующий код:
@dp.callback_query(F.data == 'bt21')
async def process_button_1_press(callback: CallbackQuery):
    photo = FSInputFile("monitoring.jpg")
    await callback.message.edit_text(text='<b>Текст</b>', reply_markup=keyboards.keyboard8, parse_mode='html')
    await callback.message.answer_photo(photo=photo)

который отправляет при нажатии Inline кнопки "bt21" текст и фото раздельно, ну понятно, потому что 2 await со своими методами.
Как мне сделать вывод изображения и текста в 1 await?

Решил с помощью caption=
т.е.:
@dp.callback_query(F.data == 'bt21')
async def process_button_1_press(callback: CallbackQuery):
    photo = FSInputFile("monitoring.jpg")
    await callback.message.answer_photo(photo=photo, caption="Текст")

Только правда образовалась другая проблема, в await callback.message.answer_photo не передается Inline клавиатура....
